# Set multiple turn servers in Gstream WebRTCBin

Tags: gstreamer, python-gstreamer

How to add multiple turn server urls to a `webrtcbin`, when using [gst-python](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-python)?

I know how to set a single url with:

```
webrtcbin.set_property("turn-server",turn_url)
```

But I want to add more URLs. [Documentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-bad/html/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-webrtcbin.html) says

> The TURN server of the form turn(s)://username:password@host:port.
> This is a convenience property, use #GstWebRTCBin::add-turn-server if
> you wish to use multiple TURN servers.

Answer (score 1):

[add-turn-server](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-bad/html/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-webrtcbin.html#GstWebRTCBin-add-turn-server) is a signal, so use `emit`:

```
webrtcbin.emit("add-turn-server", "turns://...")
```